# column ambiguosly defined error in toad for oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, toad

I am working in toad for oracle and have written this SQL query but it is giving an 
error:

[Error] Execution (65: 3): ORA-00918: column ambiguously defined

Below is my SQL query I have tried to give aliases to differentiate between the columns.

```
 select HR.EMPLOYEES.FIRST_NAME||' '||HR.EMPLOYEES.LAST_NAME AS 
 Full_Name,HR.EMPLOYEES.SALARY as sal,HR.EMPLOYEES.JOB_ID as ji,
 HR.EMPLOYEES.COMMISSION_PCT as cmpct,HR.EMPLOYEES.MANAGER_ID as 
 mgid,HR.EMPLOYEES.DEPARTMENT_ID as dep,HR.DW_COUNTRIES.C_ID as 
 country,HR.DW_REGION.R_ID as region,
 HR.LOCATIONS.LOCATION_ID as loc
 from HR.EMPLOYEES
 join HR.DEPARTMENTS ON 
 HR.EMPLOYEES.DEPARTMENT_ID=HR.DEPARTMENTS.DEPARTMENT_ID
join HR.DEPARTMENTS ON HR.DEPARTMENTS.LOCATION_ID=HR.LOCATIONS.LOCATION_ID
join HR.LOCATIONS   ON HR.LOCATIONS.COUNTRY_ID=HR.DW_COUNTRIES.C_ID
join HR.DW_COUNTRIES ON HR.DW_COUNTRIES.R_ID=HR.DW_REGION.R_ID
where HR.DW_COUNTRIES.C_ID='US'
AND HR.EMPLOYEES.HIRE_DATE BETWEEN TO_DATE('16/08/2002','DD/MM/YYYY') AND 
TO_DATE('07/12/2007','DD/MM/YYYY')
AND HR.DW_REGION.R_ID=2
AND HR.LOCATIONS.LOCATION_ID=1700
AND HR.EMPLOYEES.DEPARTMENT_ID=90
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have used table HR.DEPARTMENTS twice in your query and this is the source of the problem. Are you absolutely sure that you have to join this table twice? You also had some unclear joins. I fixed them but didn't test the query.

```
 select HR.EMPLOYEES.FIRST_NAME||' '||HR.EMPLOYEES.LAST_NAME AS 
 Full_Name,HR.EMPLOYEES.SALARY as sal,HR.EMPLOYEES.JOB_ID as ji,
 HR.EMPLOYEES.COMMISSION_PCT as cmpct,HR.EMPLOYEES.MANAGER_ID as 
 mgid,HR.EMPLOYEES.DEPARTMENT_ID as dep,HR.DW_COUNTRIES.C_ID as 
 country,HR.DW_REGION.R_ID as region,
 HR.LOCATIONS.LOCATION_ID as loc
 from HR.EMPLOYEES
 join HR.DEPARTMENTS ON 
 HR.EMPLOYEES.DEPARTMENT_ID=HR.DEPARTMENTS.DEPARTMENT_ID
join HR.LOCATIONS    ON HR.DEPARTMENTS.LOCATION_ID=HR.LOCATIONS.LOCATION_ID
join HR.DW_COUNTRIES ON HR.LOCATIONS.COUNTRY_ID=HR.DW_COUNTRIES.C_ID
join HR.DW_REGION    ON HR.DW_COUNTRIES.R_ID=HR.DW_REGION.R_ID
where HR.DW_COUNTRIES.C_ID='US'
AND HR.EMPLOYEES.HIRE_DATE BETWEEN TO_DATE('16/08/2002','DD/MM/YYYY') AND 
TO_DATE('07/12/2007','DD/MM/YYYY')
AND HR.DW_REGION.R_ID=2
AND HR.LOCATIONS.LOCATION_ID=1700
AND HR.EMPLOYEES.DEPARTMENT_ID=90
```

Comment: Wrobel thank you yeah it was a mistake of using departments 2 times

Comment: JacekWrobel can you help me with the date also because by using between it excludes the 16/08/2002 date and starts with the next date but I want results starting from 16/08/2002 to 07/12/2007 both dates included

Comment: @zainulabidin BETWEEN condition like COL1 BETWEEN V1 AND V2 can be translated to COL1 >= V1 AND COL1 <= V2 so this is strange that employees hired on 16/08/2002 were excluded by this condition. Check if other conditions are met for these employees. For the right condition V2 there is a chance that employees hired on 07/12/2007 were filtered out by BETWEEN because TO_DATE converts this data string to 2007-12-07 00:00:00 so if HIRE_DATE stores also the time part then they will be filtered out. You can bypass this problem using TRUNC(HR.EMPLOYEES.HIRE_DATE) BETWEEN and so on.

Comment: OK I will try and see if i got perfect results from the query